# Using ruby REE, what mysql libs do I need to install via aptitude install?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using ruby REE, what mysql libs do I need to install via aptitude install?

I have rails 3.03, I installed the latest mysql now I believe I need a driver right? or libs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gem install the mysql2 driver. You generally don't want to install Ruby libs through the distro.

Comment: like: sudo aptitude install libmysql-ruby1.8 ?

Comment: @Blankman Don't use aptitude with Ruby libs. They will almost always be out of date. Use `sudo gem install mysql2` instead.